# how to differentiate different parts of a same object

Tags: animation, game-engine

I am relatively new to blender. I am making a game in which a guy collects 4 different books and places it in the corresponding shelf in a cupboard. (The cupboard and the shelf are extruded from a single cube). I have no problem in identifying and picking up the book. But how do I put it in the corresponding shelf? Since all are extruded from the same cube, its not possible to assign different properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place an invisible plane above a shelf that you want to be clickable. This way you create a relationship between the plane and the corresponding shelf.